# ZXing WinRT unable to decode short QRCode

Tags: windows-runtime, qr-code, zxing

I'm trying to decode QRCode in windows store app using ZXing.

When trying to get data from:
http://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=QE3FHB01658NFG%239QM&size=490x490

I get an NullReferenceException, at line

```
 reader.Decode(writeableBmp);
```

It behaves same way with other code of the same size.
However windows phone version of ZXing is capable of reading this code.

Is there any way to make this work on RT?

I have already tried to find another QRCode reading library, but I failed to find any capable of reading this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is fixed with revision 86482 of ZXing.Net. You can build your own version from the sources of the repository or wait for the next official release which includes the fix.
There is a discussion thread in the codeplex forum about that error:
https://zxingnet.codeplex.com/discussions/446214

Comment: Worked like a charm, only had to remove signing from project properties. Thanks